# How to access fields in firestore document snapshot in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
  Future fetch_name(String? uid) async {
    DocumentSnapshot document = await user_collection.doc(uid).get();
    var user_data = document.data();
    print(user_data['name'])
  }
```

I'm getting and an error whenever I try to access the data with bracket notation,
and somehow the the get() method didnt return a Map<String,dynamic> but an object?.
I don't if it's about null safety or maybe i'm doing it wrong cause I,m still learning.
how can I retrieve a field from the get method?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the exact error as well as the document you're trying to read.  Without those, we can't really tell what's going on here.

Comment: I think you could provide some more details about the error. Accessing data with `[]` notation is only possible with [Typed CollectionReference and DocumentReference](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#typing-collectionreference-and-documentreference) and if you are not doing that way then try `user_data.name`.